# A finite object in Set is a finite Set

Tags: category-theory

I'd like to prove that an object of $\bf{Set}$ is finite iff it is a finite set. Finite object is defined as being small with respect to a finite cardinal; here's the definition of smallness I'm assuming:

"Let $k$ be a cardinal and $\mathscr{C}$ a cocomplete category. An object $A \in \mathscr{C}$ is said to be $\textit{$k$-small}$ iff for all $k$-filtered ordinal $\lambda$ (which means that $cof(\lambda) >k$ strictly) and for all  colimit preserving-functors $X: \lambda \to \mathscr{C}$ we have that the canonical morphism of sets $$colim_{\beta<\lambda}\mathscr{C}(A,X_{\beta}) \to \mathscr{C}(A,colim_{\beta < \lambda} X_{\beta})$$ is an isomorphism".

I'm able to prove that "finite set$\implies$finite object", but the converse gives me some problems. I tried to suppose that it's an infinite set and to use it's cardinality as an infinite cardinal that gives an absurd with such an iso, but I got stuck..

Any help or any hint is welcome! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your functor $F$ should be $X$, isn't it?

Comment: Of course, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm missing something or you only lack the easy side of [[LPAC]](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Locally+Presentable+and+Accessible+Categories) Example 1.2.1?

Every set is the directed colimit of its finite subsets. Hence if $K$ is a finite object, then you must have that $1_K\colon K\to K=\varinjlim{}_{F\in \mathcal P_0(K)} F$ must factor through one of the inclusions of a finite subset of $K$; hence $K$ is a finite set.

Comment: Nice proof. @Lano: I think you should consider tetrapharmakon's as your best answer -though I wouldn't mind if you upvoted mine.   :-)

Comment: But your counterexample is really good!

Comment: Thanks, I like it. But the proof is yours.   :-)

Comment: That is precisely what I had in mind, besides the fact that I made a mistake in computing the colimit of those hom-sets :)

Answer (score 2):

Could be the following a naïve counter-example? That is, an infinite set which is not small.

Even better: could it be generalized as to prove "infinite set" $\Longrightarrow$ "non finite object"?

I don't know: I'm just asking. So, consider this just as a question, more than an answer if you whish.

Take as $\mathcal{C}$ the category of sets, $\mathbf{Set}$, $A = \mathbb{N}$ and $X : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ the functor $X_n = \{ 1, \dots , n \}$. Then, on the left handside of your canonical morphism you would have:

$$
\mathrm{colim}_n \mathbf{Set}\ (\mathbb{N}, X_n) = \mathrm{colim}_n \{1, \dots , n \}^{\mathbb{N}} = \bigcup_n \{1, \dots , n \}^{\mathbb{N}}  \ .
$$

Here, $\{1, \dots , n \}^{\mathbb{N}} $ is the set of all sequences you can make out of the first $n$ natural numbers.

On the other hand, at the other end of your canonical morphism, you would have:

$$
\mathbf{Set}(\mathbb{N}, \mathrm{colim}_n X_n) = \mathbf{Set}(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}  \ .
$$

That is, the set of all sequences of natural numbers.

Then, your canonical map cannot be a bijection. Namely, the sequence of natural numbers $(n) = (1, 2, 3, \dots , n, \dots )$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, obviously, but doesn't belong to the set on the left hand side, since it doesn't belong to any of the subsets $ \{1, \dots , n \}^{\mathbb{N}} $.

Comment: I thought of a similar argument, but I made a mistake in computing a colimit. I think this should work for each set: suppose $A$ is an infinite set which is a finite object in Set. Then its cardinality is an infinite cardinal whose cofinality is surely bigger than each finite cardinal. Thus we should have that isomorphism, which is impossible by a generalization of the above argument.